# Unable to install yum downloadonly plugin on RHEL8

Tags: linux, plugins, rhel8

I am trying to install Yum downloadonly  plugin using $yum install yum-downloadonly but i get " Error: Unable to find a match: yum-downloadonly". I am using RHEL 8. Any help in this regard is greatly appreciated.

I am using RHEL8.3

Comment: Try running yum search downloadonly to see if the application appears

Answer (score -1):

On RHEL8.x you can achieve that via dnf which has such functionality already built-in:

```
dnf download rootsh
```

or including dependencies:

```
dnf download rootsh --resolve
```

Taken from: https://linoxide.com/download-packages-without-installing-rpm-distros/